# configure confixtx.yaml file?

Tags: bash, yaml, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I'm trying to build a Hyperledger Fabric network with the following

- Smartforce[Orderer Org]

  Falcon.io [ORG1]

  Frost.io [ORG2]

I have generated all cryptographic materials using cryptogen tool.
now looking to build gensis block using configtxgen tool.

Here is `configtx.yaml`:

```
Profiles:
  TwoOrgOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *Smartforce

    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - *BusinessPartner1
          - *BusinessPartner2

  TwoOrgChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *BusinessPartner1
        - *BusinessPartner2

Organizations:
  - &Smartforce
    Name: smartforce
    ID: SmartforceMSP
    MSPDir: /home/falcon/iq-smartforce/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/smartforce.io/msp

  - &BusinessPartner1
    Name: BusinessPartner1
    ID: FalconMSP
    MSPDir: /home/falcon/iq-smartforce/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/falcon.io/msp


  - &BusinessPartner2
    Name: BusinessPartner2
    ID: FrostMSP
    MSPDir: /home/frost/iq-smartforce/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/frost.io/msp


Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: solo

  Addresses:
    - orderer.smartforce.io:7050

  BatchTimeout: 2s

  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

  Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:
```

When I run the command :

```
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
```

I get the following error:

```
2018-12-12 14:55:55.834 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> WARN 001 Omitting the channel ID for configtxgen is deprecated.  Explicitly passing the channel ID will be required in the future, defaulting to 'testchainid'.
2018-12-12 14:55:55.834 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 002 Loading configuration
2018-12-12 14:55:55.834 IST [common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 003 Error reading configuration:  While parsing config: yaml: unknown anchor 'OrdererDefaults' referenced
2018-12-12 14:55:55.834 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] func1 -> CRIT 004 Error reading configuration: While parsing config: yaml: unknown anchor 'OrdererDefaults' referenced
panic: Error reading configuration: While parsing config: yaml: unknown anchor 'OrdererDefaults' referenced [recovered]
    panic: Error reading configuration: While parsing config: yaml: unknown anchor 'OrdererDefaults' referenced

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Panic(0xc4201abe30, 0xc42048fd10, 0x1, 0x1)
    /w/workspace/fabric-nightly-release-job-release-1.2-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging/logger.go:188 +0xbd
main.main.func1()
    /w/workspace/fabric-nightly-release-job-release-1.2-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:254 +0x1ae
panic(0xc6ea00, 0xc42048fd00)
    /opt/go/go1.10.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:505 +0x229
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Panic(0xc4201abc80, 0xc420484ae0, 0x2, 0x2)
    /w/workspace/fabric-nightly-release-job-release-1.2-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging/logger.go:188 +0xbd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig.Load(0x7ffdcf041294, 0x15, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1)
    /w/workspace/fabric-nightly-release-job-release-1.2-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:277 +0x469
main.main()
    /w/workspace/fabric-nightly-release-job-release-1.2-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:265 +0xce7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In YAML all anchors ( those tokens starting with `&`) need to precede any references to them (using aliases, the tokens starting with `*`) in the file.

So in the root-level mapping you should put your key `Profiles` and its value after the key `Organizations`, `Orderer` and `Application` (and their values):

```
Organizations:
  - &Smartforce
    Name: smartforce
    ID: SmartforceMSP
    MSPDir: /home/falcon/iq-smartforce/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/smartforce.io/msp

  - &BusinessPartner1
    Name: BusinessPartner1
    ID: FalconMSP
    MSPDir: /home/falcon/iq-smartforce/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/falcon.io/msp

  - &BusinessPartner2
    Name: BusinessPartner2
    ID: FrostMSP
    MSPDir: /home/frost/iq-smartforce/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/frost.io/msp

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: solo

  Addresses:
    - orderer.smartforce.io:7050

  BatchTimeout: 2s

  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

  Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:

Profiles:
  TwoOrgOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *Smartforce

    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - *BusinessPartner1
          - *BusinessPartner2

  TwoOrgChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *BusinessPartner1
        - *BusinessPartner2
```