# Hyperledger Fabric configtxgen - Error reading config: map merge requires map or sequence of maps as the value

Tags: yaml, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to setup a simple Fabric network with the following:

- Orderer Organization [abccoinOrderers]
- Sample Organization [ABC]

After generating the all the necessary files using cryptogen tool, running the configtxgen command gives the following error:

```
student@abc:~/Desktop/fabric/network$ configtxgen -profile DefaultBlockOrderingService -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block -configPath $PWD
    2019-12-26 12:35:42.131 MST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> WARN 001 Omitting the channel ID for configtxgen for output operations is deprecated.  Explicitly passing the channel ID will be required in the future, defaulting to 'testchainid'.
    2019-12-26 12:35:42.136 MST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 002 Loading configuration
    2019-12-26 12:35:42.137 MST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> PANI 003 Error reading configuration:  While parsing config: yaml: map merge requires map or sequence of maps as the value
    2019-12-26 12:35:42.137 MST [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 004 Error reading configuration:  While parsing config: yaml: map merge requires map or sequence of maps as the value
    panic: Error reading configuration:  While parsing config: yaml: map merge requires map or sequence of maps as the value [recovered]
        panic: Error reading configuration:  While parsing config: yaml: map merge requires map or sequence of maps as the value
```

Here is the configtx.yaml

```
Organizations:
    - &abccoinOrderers
        Name: abccoinOrderersMSP
        ID: abccoinOrderersMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/abccoin.com/msp
    - &ABC
        Name: ABCMSP
        ID: ABCMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ABC.abccoin.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
          - Host: Andy.ABC.abccoin.com
            Port: 7051

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

Orderer:
    - &DevModeOrdering
        OrdererType: solo
        Addresses:  
            - Devorderer.abccoin.com:7050
        BatchTimeout: 2s
        BatchSize:
            MaxMessageCount: 1

Profiles:
    DefaultBlockOrderingService:
        Orderer:
            <<: *DevModeOrdering
            Organizations:
                - *abccoinOrderers
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *ABC


    abcMembersOnly:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *ABC
```

I've already tried rearranging the code blocks as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740104/configure-confixtx-yaml-file). I've also tried pacing the "<<" key in quotes as mentioned in this issue [YML document "<<: value" cannot be parsed #245](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/245) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 errors in the`configtx.yaml`.

1. **Orderer:** Is a map type or object type, not an array or slice type. When you define parameters using `-`, it is used as an array in yaml.

```
Orderer:
    // remove -
    &DevModeOrdering
      OrdererType: solo
      Addresses:  
          - Devorderer.abccoin.com:7050
      BatchTimeout: 2s
      BatchSize:
          MaxMessageCount: 1
```

2. **Application:** You must declare `Organizations:` parameter. It can be empty. If you don't declare anything in that, it will not compile. To check you should try to convert the yaml into json in any online convertor.

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
```